# Service Reference Proxy method Generation

Tags: asp.net, wcf, proxy

I have two Biztalk applications, each of which expose a webservice port, 
I'm consuming them in an ASP.NET client using the 'Add service reference' tool from within  the VS2010 GUI to generate the proxies.

But the proxy interface is slightly different in both.  One takes two parameters, returns the 'response'  via a parameter using the out keyword and has a void return type,

the other takes one parameter and returns the response using a typed return value.

I'm confused as to what is causing the difference in behavior, is something I'm doing as part of the creation of the references (as far as I can tell I've used the same process)  or is it something about the server/WSDL  I'm consuming?

EDIT -As per Grahams comment the type of proxy interface generated seems to depend on whether there is a namespace or not.  I'll give the answer to whoever can put together the clearest description of what exactly is happening there.

Comment: Do the two services use the same response class? Do the two services use different namespaces?

Comment: Seems to be a namespace problem alright, one of the services does have an explicit namespace and the other does. Without the namespace it generates the parameterised version ( that is the one with the 'out' parameter')

Comment: Graham,  given the lack of interest in giving  a detailed description do you want to put your response down as the answer and I'll  mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the inclusing of a namespace in one of the services is what was triggering the difference in the proxy code generation. It's still not clear exactly why this is the case however.